# ESLint showing me error and suggest to use try...catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch, fetch

Currently, I was taking a course:**Front-End Web Development with React** in coursera, and I was stuck at a point where the instructor was showing how to fetch data using cross-fetch. Here he was showing

```js
export const fetchDishes = () => (dispatch) => {
  return fetch(baseUrl + 'dishes')
    .then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error(
            'Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText
          );
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      //manually handle error if the server didn't response
      (error) => {
        var errmess = new Error(error.message);
        throw errmess;
      }
    )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((dishes) => dispatch(addDishes(dishes)));
    .catch(error => dispatch(dishesFailed(error.message)));
};
```

But my ESLint showing me error and suggest to use try...catch block.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAC7T.png)

But I was wondering why this error occurs even though the instructor write it as above and run the application perfectly? I have no idea how to convert this code into a try...catch block.

---

@erik_m give a solution but I did get that is semicolon mean terminate the promise chain? And one more thing which temp me that the instructor didn't import fetch (like `import fetch from 'cross-fetch'`)then how my application is using fetch? He just showed to do yarn add cross-fetch@2.1.0 Did fetch is inherited by default with react application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are terminating the call one line above the catch.

```
.then((response) => response.json())
    .then((dishes) => dispatch(addDishes(dishes)));
    .catch(error => dispatch(dishesFailed(error.message)));
```

on the line right above the .catch, remove the semicolon, and the paren. Your catch is not properly part of your then statement.

Edit: Can you try to replace the last three lines with this? You have your parens and semi colons in the wrong place. So the program thinks you are ending your promise after the second then, so it is not recognizing the "catch" portion.

```
.then((response) => response.json())
    .then((dishes) => dispatch(addDishes(dishes))
.catch(error => dispatch(dishesFailed(error.message))));
```

Comment: Oh, did semicolon mean terminate the promise chain? @erik_m ? And one more thing which temp me that he didn't import fetch then how my application is using fetch? He just showed to do `yarn add cross-fetch@2.1.0` Did fetch is inherited by default with react application?

Comment: @falamiw, I added an edit to my answer with the correct syntax. That ought to get rid of your compiler error. As for how exactly your instructor is inheriting the library, I would have to see more code.

Comment: @falamiw, did that fix your build? If so, would you mind marking this question as answered? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for late accepting @erik_m Yes your solution fix my problem. As you said you would need to see more code [here](https://pastebin.com/uwYCVsK0) this the complete code. Let me know if you can figure out this.